# Modify variable get from Vuex Store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

This question maybe the most noob outwhere, but I cannot find out.

First, assign variable from store state

`this.currentLoadNode = this.$store.state.loadNode`

Modify variable

`this.currentLoadNode.shift();`

**EDIT to avoid misreading: I don't look for modify Vuex state (I know commit mutation) , I just want to modify my `currentLoadNode` variable. However, in a mystery way, Vuex also modify `loadNode` state and throw me this error**

> [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."

Hope anyone enter this issue and could give me a help. Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they point to the same address in memory. You can try creating a copy

```
this.currentLoadNode = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.loadNode))
```

or ES6 syntax

```
this.currentLoadNode = [...this.$store.state.loadNode]
```

Comment: I also think that Vuex document should mention about this. The case user want to modify variable get from state, they must clone variable, not assign equal